# Array of Index to colors to array of colors in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Having an array (2d) with index of colors is there a way to replace the index by its color in one step not element by element?

Example:

```
colors=[[255,0,0],[125,222,11]]
im_x=[[0,0],[1,0]]

#the result must be:

im_c= [[[255,0,0],[255,0,0]],[[125,222,11],[255,0,0]]
```

I have try
colors[im_x] but it does not work :(

Comment: The problem is that you have not defined arrays...

Comment: Can you please be a bit more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the arrays as `numpy` arrays, and then index them as you were trying to:

```
import numpy as np
colors = np.array([[255,0,0],[125,222,11]])
im_x = np.array([[0,0],[1,0]])

colors[im_x]

array([[[255,   0,   0],
        [255,   0,   0]],

       [[125, 222,  11],
        [255,   0,   0]]])
```